# Converse of Lagrange theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The order of the subgroup divides the order of its group:
So for example if the order of a group was 8, does there **need** to be 4 subgroups of orders 8,4,2,1 each? Also can 2 subgroups have the same order.

Comment: It may work for $8$, but not in general. In general, there doesn't need to be a subgroup for each factor, and two subgroups may be different and have the same order.

Comment: The group $A_4$, the even permutations on a set of $4$ elements, has order $4! = 12$, but contains no subgroup of order $6$.

Comment: The Sylow  theorems will tell you what subgroups must be present for any given order.

Answer (score 0):

Given the structure theorem of Finite Abelian Groups, it *is* true that any abelian group $G$ of order $n$ has at least one subgroup of order $k$ for each factor $k$ of $n$. Moreover: $$\text{(there is only one such subgroup for each $k$) $\Longleftrightarrow G$ is cyclic.}$$

This last point also answers your last question.

Back to first question, it is wrong for non-abelian groups, with the easiest examples given by alternating groups $A_4$ and $A_5$ having no subgroups of index $2$.